# Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookResponseStatusException: Received Facebook error response (code 1): An unknown error occurred

Tags: java, php, facebook-fql, restfb, json

I have seen the examples for FqlMultiQuery at restfb.com and https://code.google.com/p/restfb/issues/detail?id=8 and the examples involves separate queries.

However, I can't seem to find an example on how to use FqlMultiQuery for similar queries. What i mean by similar queries is something like the following template/sample:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid=220439
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid=239203
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid=<<iterate_over_this>>
```

I was trying to use FqlMultiQuery to run similar queries all over and obtain a JsonObject which I can use *.toString()* to output as JSON. Still I gave it a shot, hoping things would work. Unfortunately, they didn't.

**Here is the stack for RestFB 1.6.12:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookResponseStatusException: Received Facebook error response (code 1): An unknown error occurred
  at com.restfb.BaseFacebookClient$DefaultLegacyFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(BaseFacebookClient.java:143)
  at com.restfb.BaseFacebookClient.throwLegacyFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(BaseFacebookClient.java:204)
  at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:666)
  at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:630)
  at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:592)
  at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery(DefaultFacebookClient.java:396)
  at com.hadoopfun.facebookanalysissimple.FacebookAnalysisProject.main(FacebookAnalysisProject.java:89)
```

**Here is the code for generating FQL Requests and executing FqlMultiQuery:**

```
Map<String, String> queries = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(JsonObject friend : fbUser.getFriends()) {
    String friendId = friend.getString("uid");
    queries.put(friendId, "SELECT post_id, message, type, comment_info, like_info, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=" + friendId + " AND actor_id=me() LIMIT 1000");
}

JsonObject multiqueryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery(queries, JsonObject.class);

System.out.println(multiqueryResults.toString());
```

**What is the expected output? What am I trying to do?**

I was trying to print the results of my query out. However, what I got was the exception in the stack pasted above.